# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getNumFrames' of undefined

Tags: html5-canvas, adobe, createjs

I created an html canvas with Adobe Animate, it works fine in debug mode but you I publish my website on filesystem I get the following error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getNumFrames' of undefined
```

I search about this and find out

> Sprite sheets do not work from the local filesystem.

But I wonder if that is true, why and how can I use it on filesystem ?

Comment: You are likely not running a web server, instead you are trying to load the html as a file on your filesystem.  A lot of stuff does not work when you run an application like this.  Run you app via a web server like IIS Express or apache and that error should go away.

Comment: @QBM5 is right -- by default, Adobe Animate tests using a local webserver now -- and the built-in SpriteSheet loading uses XHR (the spritesheet data is JSON data, which requires it). Look into running a local server (you can do it with 1 line in the terminal or cmd).